# Why are explicit forall quantifiers necessary for rank-n types?

Tags: haskell, types, higher-rank-types, rank-n-types, scott-encoding

When I declare this newtype:

```
newtype ListScott a = 
  ListScott { 
  unconsScott :: (a -> ListScott a -> r) -> r -> r 
}
```

which would define the hypothetical rank-2 type `ListScott :: ((a -> ListScott a -> r) -> r -> r) -> ListScott a`, the compiler complains about `r` not being in scope. Isn't it apparent from the type signature that I want to pass a first class polymorphic function to `ListScott`?

Why do I need an explicit type quantifier for `r` for cases like this?

I am not a type theorist and have probably overlooked something...

Comment: Because it is much more common to write data types without higher rank types; and because programmers make mistakes. It is not unreasonable that one could forget to include a type variable in the lhs of the declaration, in which case your desired syntax silently ignore the mistake and produce very confusing errors later on. Any syntax which is very close to a common typo is just bad syntax, no matter how convenient it might be in other cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a question of programming language design. It could be inferred in the way you suggest, but I argue that it is a bad idea.

> Isn't it apparent from the type signature that I want to pass a first class polymorphic function to ListScott?

I don't think that we can obviously tell that much from this definition.

### Universal or existential? Conflict with GADT notation

Here's something we can write with the `GADTs` extension:

```
data ListScott a where
  ListScott :: { unconsScott :: (a -> ListScott a -> r) -> r -> r } -> ListScott a
```

Here `r` is quantified existentially in the `unconsScott` field, so the constructor has the first type below:

```
ListScott :: forall a r. ((a -> ListScott a -> r) -> r -> r) -> ListScott a
-- as opposed to
ListScott :: forall a. (forall r. (a -> ListScott a -> r) -> r -> r) -> ListScott a
```

### Inference disables error detection

What if `r` is instead meant to be a parameter to `ListScott`, but we simply forgot to add it? I believe that is a reasonably probable mistake, because both the hypothetical `ListScott r a` and `ListScott a` can serve as representations of lists in some ways. Then inference of binders would result in an erroneous type definition being accepted, and errors being reported elsewhere, once the type gets used (hopefully not too far, but that would still be worse than an error at the definition itself).

Explicitness also prevents typos where a type constructor gets mistyped as a type variable:

```
newtype T = T { unT :: maybe int }
-- unlikely to intentionally mean "forall maybe int. maybe int"
```

There is not enough context in a type declaration alone to confidently guess the meaning of variables, thus we should be forced to bind variables properly.

### Readability

Consider record of functions:

```
data R a = R
  { f :: (r -> r) -> r -> r
  , g :: r -> r
  }

data R r a = R
  { f :: (r -> r) -> r -> r
  , g :: r -> r
  }
```

We have to look to the left of `=` to determine whether `r` is bound there, and if not we have to mentally insert binders in every field. I find that makes the first version hard to read because the `r` variable in the two fields would actually not be under the same binder, but it certainly looks otherwise at a glance.

### Comparison to similar constructs

Note that something similar to what you suggested happens with type classes, which can be seen as a sort of record:

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Most arguments above apply as well, and I would thus prefer to write that class as:

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

A similar thing could be said of local type annotations. However, top-level signatures are different:

```
id :: a -> a
```

That unambiguously means `id :: forall a. a -> a`, because there is no other level where `a` could be bound.

Comment: I agree (+1). Note that we already have some ambiguity with `ScopedTypeVariables` since e.g. in `let f :: forall a. a -> a ; f x = let g :: T a b ; g = undefined in x` the type of `g` is `forall b. T a b` since `a` is rigid in-scope. Renaming `a` in `f` would cause `g :: forall a b. T a b`. This is simlar to the issue you mention above.

Answer (score 4):

The point is that the constructor would not have the rank-1 (yes, one) type you mention:
(quantifiers added for clarity)

```
ListScott1 :: forall a r. ((a -> ListScott a -> r) -> r -> r) -> ListScott a
```

but the following rank-2 type

```
ListScott2 :: forall a. (forall r. (a -> ListScott a -> r) -> r -> r) -> ListScott a
```

So, rank-2 are indeed involved in the type checking of your program.

Note that, if `f :: (Bool -> ListScott Bool -> Char) -> Char -> Char`, then the first constructor above would make `ListScott1 f :: ListScott Bool` well-typed, but this is not what we want. Indeed, using the second constructor, `ListScott2 f` is ill-typed.

Indeed, for `ListScott2 f :: ListScott Bool` to be well-typed, we need a polymorphic `f`, having type `f :: forall r. (Bool -> ListScott Bool -> r) -> r -> r`.